# How to convert ArrayList<String> to json array of string values in java

Tags: java, json

I have a list of String which I wish to convert to Json.

```java
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList()l
    list.add("IR01");
    list.add("00112");
    list.add("0ID001");
```

By using `list.toString()`, getting response string as `[IR01,00112,0ID001]`, but one of my requirement needs to send json string like `"["\IR01","\00112","\0ID001\"]" to StringEntity class.

I don't know how to continue from here. A little help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

first i advise you to use List instead of arraylist
In fact, everywhere you need to declare a reference variable, you should always use the supertype, like Map for passing HashMap, Set for giving HashSet, and List for passing ArrayList, LinkedList, or Vector.
And now your answere

```
String json = new Gson().toJson(list);
```